# MongoDB - loop through each database and run a command

Tags: mongodb

My MongoDB instance have several databases of same design. I want to loop through each database and apply unique indexes to several collections in each database.

I understand how to apply the new unique index to the collection, but how do I loop through each database and run the command on each?

```
db.collection.createIndex (
    { email : 1 },
    { unique : true, collation : { locale : "en", strength : 2 } }
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general idea is to loop through the list returned from the commands

[**`db.adminCommand('listDatabases')`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/listDatabases/)

or

**`db.getMongo().getDBNames()`**

Within the loop, create the db object with **[`getDB()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/Mongo.getDB/)** method and loop through each db's collection with **[`db.getCollectionNames()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.getCollectionNames/#db.getCollectionNames)**, get the collection object with **[`db.getCollection()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.getCollection/#db.getCollection)** or **`db[collectionName]`** bracket syntax and create the index, something like the following:

```
mongo = db.getMongo(); // or mongo = new Mongo();
mongo.getDBNames().forEach(function(dbname){
    db = mongo.getDB(dbname);
    db.getCollectionNames().forEach(function(collectionName) {
        collection = db.getCollection(collectionName); // or db[collectionMame]
        indexes = collection.getIndexes();
        print("Indexes for " + collectionName + ":");
        printjson(indexes);

        emailIdx = indexes.filter(function(idx){ return idx.key === { "email": 1 }; });
        if (emailIdx.length < 1) {
            collection.createIndex (
                { email : 1 },
                { unique : true, collation : { locale : "en", strength : 2 } }
            )
        }
    });
})
```

A useful Mongo shell cheat sheet can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/kgorman/488172).